# Kummer equation, solution to find optimal value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, hypergeometric-function

Suppose V follows the mean reverting process $$dV=η( ̅V-V)Vdt+σVdz$$
I want to find the optimal investment rule, and using Itos's lemma I get that the differential equation that F(V) must satisfy

$$ 1/2 σ^2 V^2 F''(V)+[r-μ+η( ̅V-V)]VF'(V) -rF = 0$$
F(V) must satisfy the boundary conditions

$$F(0)=0$$

$$F(V^* )=V^*-I$$

$$F' (V^* )=1$$

The solution is stated to be given by: 
$$F(V)=AV^θ H(2η/σ^2  V;θ,b)$$
The solution is a confluent hypergeometric function H(x;θ,b(θ)) 
How do I solve for V and A?

I have calculated the value for θ and b. But I don't know how to proceed.
In the book it says that A is a constant to be determined. We find A as well as the critical value V* at which it is optimal to invest , from the remaining two boundry conditions.

And hence I am lost..

Because the confluent hypergeometric
function is an infinite series, A and V* must be found
numerically... What does this mean? Isn't there an analytical closed form solution here?

see http://web.mit.edu/rpindyck/www/Courses/RO_P2_Hand%20Outs.pdf from slide 42 down for the whole set of equations..

Hope someone can help me. Do not know how to solve this :/

Comment: Please improve your missing and my temporary formating. Then describe **all** your symbols (especially: what is $H, \Omega$?)

Comment: I have replaced `F^'` by `F'` in your post. You should have noticed that what you wrote did not compile correctly; `$F^'$` is displayed as $F^'$. (Of course, if that is not what you meant, you should go ahead and edit your post, adding necessary clarifications.) To be more specific, the last equation in your post `$F^' (V^* )=Ω^' (V^* )=V^*-1$` was displayed as: $F^' (V^* )=Ω^' (V^* )=V^*-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Does the edit make it any clearer? I tried to explain some more @gammatester

Comment: Your source uses a very unusual notation for the confluent hypergeometric
function, the standard notation for Kummer's function is $M(a,b,z)$ or
$_1F_1(a,b,z)$ and the relation to your $H$ is
$H(x;\theta,b(\theta))=M(\theta, b, x).$ I guess that you **do not solve** for
$V$ (i.e. compute $F^{-1}$) but solve for the critical value $V^{*}$. I am
pretty sure that cannot be done analytically. Once you have $V^{*}$ computing
$A$ is easy.

Comment: I am very new to this topic, but yet I am writing my master thesis on it.  Real Option analysis that is. But I can not fathom how to solve this. How to get V*. How do I do it numerically? @gammatester